# Signing VeriFone app as default

Tags: verifone

I bought two VeriShield file signing cards. Unfortunately neither of the cards work--they each give a "wrong pin" error.

PIN Entry Try is 3. Do we see any message if the cards are locked? Can we sign the file as default and download the app to terminal? Also will there be any ownership issues if I sign the files as default for development?

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with why you are getting the wrong PIN.  There could be a few different reasons:

**VERIFY YOU HAVE THE RIGHT PIN**

When you first got your cards, each one should have come with a welcome letter telling you what the PIN is for that card.  Note that each card will have a unique PIN and that you can't mix the two up (that is--if you try to enter the PIN for card 1 on card 2, it won't work and visa-versa).

NOTE: VeriFone is not infallible--when I was in my VF training class, one student got a pair of cards that didn't work and the teacher decided he must have had the wrong PINs sent to him.  The only remedy is to contact the VF rep from whom you purchased the cards.

**CHECK FOR PROPER INSTALLATION**

1. Are you using the latest version of the File Signing Tool (FST)?  I believe the latest version is 04.01.04.  If you have an older version, go to the DevNet page and get the latest.
2. I have a note saying that the FST installer needs to be run using administrator privileges, though if I remember correctly, it will elevate itself to administrator, so this shouldn't be off too much concern.  My note also says that during the setup, you may get a message about not being able to change folder permissions, but not to worry about it.
3. Once you have the FST installed, set it to always run as administrator.  This *IS* important and it won't work if you don't.
4. The first time you run FST, you'll need to set up 2 officers and give them temporary passwords (you will be required to change the passwords on the next log-in).  Note that for some reason, VF decided to make the USER NAMES case sensitive (not just the passwords).
5. Once those users are set up, log in as those users and change the password to the "permanent" password ("permanent" as in you don't have to change it again if you don't want to).  If I'm not mistaken, you can't use one of the last (3?) passwords, so you can't use the same as the temporary password you set them up with.
6. Now log in with BOTH users that you set up and choose Change PIN.

If you are still having trouble, contact your VF rep.

> PIN Entry Try is 3. Do we see any message if the cards are locked?

I know that you do have a very limited number of retries before the card locks itself, but seeing as mine worked on my first try, I really couldn't tell you what happens as you approach and/or cross that limit.

> Can we sign the file as default and download the app to terminal?  Also will there be any ownership issues if i sign the files as default for development.

That depends on what type of terminal you are using.  If it is a Verix or VerixV (so like 3740, 3750, 3730, 510, 570) then, yes you can use a default signature (that's what I regularly do on these terminals) and no, it won't cause any problems, assuming everything else that is running on that terminal is also default-signed.  If you are using some things that ARE secure-signed, then I believe that all items must have the same sponsor to run on that terminal (I know that's true with the eVo platform, but I'm just assuming on the Verix/VerixV platforms).

HOWEVER, if you are running an eVo terminal (like 520) then you MUST use a secure signature--eVo will not accept a default certificate.  What's more, once a secure-signed program is loaded into the terminal, then ALL future applications MUST be signed using a certificate with the same sponsor, or that program will not run.  (One exception--if you run the certificate removal program, then AFTER it runs, you can load a new sponsor on.  However, note that the removal tool will not run unless it has been singed by the same sponsor).

Trying to use a default certificate should not cause any ownership problems, it just won't run.  I know that if I try and use the default certificate on my terminal that already has a sponsor, it will compare the file signatures after download and say they don't match.  I haven't tried it on a blank (no sponsor cert yet) eVo, but I suspect you would get roughly the same result.

Those file signing cards have gotten expensive recently, so if yours aren't working, then I'd get with the VF rep quickly and try to get it fixed--the longer you wait, the less likely they'll help you.